# undetected_chromedriver.v2 Proxy is not working (proxy_auth_plugin.zip)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I am using proxy_auth_plugin.zip proxy for selenium chrome webdriver but i switched to use undetected_chromedriver.v2 It's same as selenium chrome webdriver but it has better use for secuity isuess however

~

Trying to change the proxies automatic But it's not working same as how i do it on selenium chrome

python selenium chrome code that works with me :

```
import os
import zipfile
import time

from selenium import webdriver

PROXY_HOST = ''  # rotating proxy
PROXY_PORT = 0
PROXY_USER = ''
PROXY_PASS = ''




manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
          singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
          },
          bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
      };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT, PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS)


def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        os.path.join(path, 'C:\cc\chromedriver.exe'),
        chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver

def main():
    driver = get_chromedriver(use_proxy=True)
    driver.get('')
    time(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is my undetected_chromedriver.v2 code for proxy

```
import time
import random
from typing import Any, Union
import undetected_chromedriver.v2 as uc
import os
import zipfile
import time
from time import sleep


host = '107.23.19.8'
port = 3135
username = 'ggwp'
password = 'ggwp123'


manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

background_js = """
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
          singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
          },
          bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
      };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (host, port , username, password)


def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
   # opts = uc.ChromeOptions()
   # opts.add_argument(proxySetting.GetProxyText())
    #driver = uc.Chrome(options=opts)
    
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    return driver 

def main():
    driver = get_chromedriver(use_proxy=True)
    #driver.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=my+ip+address')
    driver.get('https://ipleak.net')
    time(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to run headless be advised that Chrome doesn't pick up extensions in headless mode, and what you have above is an extension setup.